# mocking a recursive class

Tags: java, junit, mockito, junit5

using Spring 2.0.3.RELEASE, JUnit Jupiter 5.7.0, Mockito 3.3.3

try to test method method01 of class Class01:

```
public class Class01 {

 private RestConnector con;
 
 public Class01(){
  con = RestConnector.getInstance();
 }

 public Response method01(String x) {
  Class01 example = new Class01();
  String x = example.isAuthenticated();
  
  // more stuff after this
  
 }
 
 public String isAuthenticated() throws IOException {
  // I do stuff
  return "a string";
 }

}
```

In the test class have tried

```
public class Class01Test{

 @Mock private Class01 class01Mock;
 
 @Spy @InjectMocks private Class01 class01;

 @Test
 public void test() throws Throwable {
  
  doReturn("I returned").when(class01).  ??? stuck here .. always goes into the isAuthenticated method
  Response result = class01.method01("a string");
 }

}
```

Currently the test is always running the real method isAuthenticated.
How to setup a mock for the field example in method method01 so that the execute skips going into method isAuthenticated?

Comment: The mock is never used since `method01` creates a new instance.  But why is a new instance being created within `method01`?  If that is really needed, then inject the mock through the constructor or pass as a parameter.

Comment: as best I understand what this is doing is it tries to connect to an external server. if it fails it tries another location. Not following what you mean by " inject the mock through the constructor or pass as a parameter"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> try to test method method01 of class Class01

Then you don't need mocks.

```
 @Test
 public void test() throws Throwable {
  Class01 c = new Class01();

  Response expected = ... ;
  assertEquals(c.method01("input"), expected);
 }
```

If you want to inject behaviour into `example` variable, you need to move it to a field

```
public class Class01 {

 private RestConnector con;
 private Class01 inner;
 
 public Class01(){
  con = RestConnector.getInstance();
 }

 Class01(Class01 c) {
   this();
   this.inner = c;
 }

 public Response method01(String x) {
  String x = inner.isAuthenticated();
  
  // more stuff after this
  
 }
```

Along with a Mock

```
@RunWith(MockitoJunitRunner.class)
public class Class01Test{

 @Mock Class01 class01Mock;

 @Test
 public void test() throws Throwable {
  Response expected = ... ;
  when(class01Mock.isAuthenticated()).thenReture(expected); ... // TODO: Setup  
 
  Class01 c = new Class01(class01Mock); // pass in the mock
  
  assertEquals(c.method01("input"), expected);
 }
```

**However**, unclear why you need a nested object of the same class when you appear to only need `this.isAuthenticated()`

Ideally, you'd also mock the `RestConnector`